# Generating an X and Y ID in a certain way

Tags: java, for-loop

I had a lot of trouble trying to find a solution to this answer because it's hard to search specifically about it. I will try my best to explain it well though.

Currently I have the following code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10000; x++){
        for(int z = 0; z < 10000; z++){
            if(!exists(x + ";" + z)){
                return x + ";" + z;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is pretty much what I want to do except the way the numbers will "generate" is like so:

> 0;0
>   0;1
>   0;2
>   0;3
>   ...
>   0;9999
>   1;0
>   1;1

I would like the numbers to generate in the following way "or similar" while still ensuring that every combination exists.

```
0;0
1;0
1;1
0;1
```

I created an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcuJZ.png) to show how the numbers should generate. It can go from bottom to left or left to bottom. ([See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcuJZ.png))

Thanks!

Comment: the return call will end the for-loop, is that the problem you are experiencing? What do you want to do with the numbers generated? Make a big string or list or maybe print them?

Comment: This bit of code will be inside a method, the exists(String s) method called inside will check if I have already used them. 

You could just ignore that method and act like I want to print out a list which would solve my problem as well.

I don't want to change the order, I want to kind of "mix" the orders.

Comment: I've seen your image and I now get the question. Is the range for `x` always the same as the range for `z` - ie is it always a square?

Comment: Yes, I have gotten a solution which solves this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int len = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) //println(i+";"+j);
  for (int k = i-1; k >= 0; k--) //println(k+";"+i);
}
```

In the code above `len` serves the purpose of defining the length of a square (`len` is 3 above which represents a 3 x 3). In your own code you picked 10000 but that is too large for printing values

What you want is easiest to do with two internal loops, one that handles vertical and the other horizontal. Other than that just arbitrarily pick which one handles the corner of each `i` iteration. In the code above the `j` loop handles the corner case

Comment: Works the most efficiently and doesn't repeat any.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you seem to be looking for is:

```
for(int distanceFromCorner = 0; distanceFromCorner < 10000; distanceFromCorner++) {
    for(int otherAxis = 0; otherAxis <= distanceFromCorner; otherAxis++) {
        if(!exists(distanceFromCorner + ";" + otherAxis))
            return distanceFromCorner + ";" + otherAxis;
        if(!exists(otherAxis + ";" + distanceFromCorner))
            return otherAxis + ";" + distanceFromCorner;
    }
}
```

Note that this (like your original algorithm) will be much slower than necessary if you want to generate a large number of IDs. (Optimizing this is a separate question)

Comment: That seems to work best, I don't think I will ever need to generate more than 100,000 IDs which can take a few seconds but that isn't a problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jupiter it might not be a problem, but if I were you, it would annoy me that it took a few seconds instead of a few microseconds.

Comment: The method is not going to be constantly called, and it will take some time to get to the point where it will take 1-2 seconds or maybe even a lot less since I'm running this inside of Eclipse.